# How to Merge Row group to one row within column group

Tags: reporting-services

I might not use/have the correct terms but, I need to merge the rows in Guideline Row Group to one row for all column groups.

[image]

eg. all rows for guideline "Delivering product/service to cus.. ect", should be one row for %, Average, Management ect: like in the image below [i will worry about order later] (this is done in HTML but now need an SSRS version)

[image]

I have 3 row groups and 1 column group, please help/advise

report design below:
[image]

Comment: Seems than on your row groups, you have added the same group that you use for columns and that makes each column value appear on different row

Comment: Have you tried deleting the "Details" row group? What are your other row groups grouped on.

Comment: As others have hinted, it looks like your row groups are grouping at a level lower than you need. I looks like you need three row groups, Stage/Department/Guideline . Remove any other row groups. Your column group is probably OK. If this does not help, post your report design, in particular the row and column groups and their associated properties.

Comment: Yes, I have those 3(Stage, Department, and Guideline) row groups and 1 column group. I have included a section of the report design

Comment: okay deleting the "Details" row group seems to have done the trick. Thank you so much